# What is the probability that two random vectors in $\mathbb{Z}_n^k$ have dot product $z$?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, modules

In particular, I'm considering the set

$S(n, k, z) = \{(x, y) \in (\mathbb{Z}_n^k)^2 \mid \langle x, y \rangle = z\}$

which contains, for any $n, k, z$ each pair of vectors $(x, y) \in (\mathbb{Z}_n^k)^2$ which has the property that $\sum_{i \in [n]} x_i y_i = z$. I want to know how much smaller this set is than $(\mathbb{Z}_n^k)^2$ itself, which I state mathematically using the following two functions:

$f(n, k, z) = |S(n, k, z)|$

$\rho(n, k, z) = \frac{f(n, k, z)}{n^{2k}}$

It's not a priori clear how to compute these functions, but I've done a little prepping of $f$ with a question on [mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/265486/how-many-pairs-of-numbers-between-0-and-n-1-are-equal-to-z-mod-n/265524#265524) as well as some simply recurrence expansion which I did myself.

I believe its clear that we can partition each $S(n, k, z)$ into sets which each have unique first components $x_1, y_1$:

$S(n, k, z) = \oplus_{(x_1^*, y_1^*) \in \mathbb{Z}^2}\{ (x, y) \in (\mathbb{Z}^k)^2 \mid x_1 = x_1^*, y_1 = y_1^*, \langle x, y\rangle = z \}$

Writing the concatenation of $a, b$ as $a.b$, it is clear that we can also write:

$S(n, k, z) = \oplus_{(x_1^*, y_1^*) \in \mathbb{Z}^2} \{ (x_1^*.x, y_1^*.y) \mid x, y \in \mathbb{Z}^k, \langle x_1^*.x, y_1^*.y \rangle = \langle x, y \rangle = z - x_1^*y_1^* \}$

and then I think its clear that:

$f(n, k, z) = \sum_{(x_1, y_1) \in \mathbb{Z}_n^2} f(n, k - 1, z - x_1y_1)$

Using the fact that $ax\equiv b (\text{mod }n)$ has $(a, n)$ solutions if $(a, n) \mid (b, n)$ and none otherwise, we can see easily that:

$f(n, 1, z) = \sum_{y \in \mathbb{Z} :(y, n) \mid (z, n)} (y, n)$

Using the fact that $|\{ y \in \mathbb{Z}_n \mid (y, n) = d \}| = \varphi(\frac{n}{d})$, we can further see that:

$f(n, 1, z) = \sum_{d \in \mathbb{Z_m}:d|(z, m)} d \varphi(\frac{n}{d})$

We can further simplify this for primes:

$f(p, 1, z) = \sum_{d \in \mathbb{Z}_p:d|(z, p)} d \varphi(\frac{p}{d})$

clearly $(z, p) = 1$ or $p$, the latter case being if $z = 0$. Let's deal with that case:

$f(p, 1, 0) = \varphi(p) + p \varphi(\frac{p}{p}) = p + p(1 - \frac{1}{p}) = 2p - 1$

and in the other case we only have the term $\varphi(p)$, as the $p$ divisor is gone because $0 < z < p, z \neq p \Rightarrow (z, p) = 1$, so we can write

$f(p, 1, z \neq 0) = \varphi(p) = p(1 - \frac{1}{p}) = p - 1$

This is great but I still can't really do much to simplify the initial recurrence and I feel like this function $f$ is going to be quite difficult to compute for most $n$. I'm looking for help simplifying $f$ for higher $k$ and for special cases of $n, z$, particularly $z = 0$, as that's an interesting case for algorithm design.